# jquery deleting parent elements which are clones

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="row trackingRow">
    <div class="large-2 medium-2 columns text-right no-margin">
        <p>Customerwise</p>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 medium-3 columns">
        <input type="text" class="radius" />
    </div>
    <div class="large-7 medium-7 columns">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="button tiny success radius">open ticket in new window</a>
        <a href="#" class="button tiny secondary radius deleteTracking"><img src="img/trash_icon.png" /></a>
        <a href="#" class="button tiny radius addAnother"><img src="img/tiny_plus_icon.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using jquery currently to clone the entire "trackingRow" div any time the "addAnother" link is clicked so that my client can enter as many IDs as the ticket has associated with it. They also need to be able to delete them. I was able to get the functionality working using:

```
<script>

    $(".addAnother").click(function () {
        var cloneDiv = $(this).closest(".trackingRow").clone();
        cloneDiv.find("a.addAnother").remove();
        cloneDiv.insertAfter($(this).closest(".trackingRow"));
    });

    $(".trackingRow").on("click", ".deleteTracking", function () {
        $(this).closest(".trackingRow").remove();
    });

</script>
```

But the removal won't work on any of the cloned trackingRow, only the original. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using delegated event handling with this:

```
$(".trackingRow").on("click", ".deleteTracking", function () {
    $(this).closest(".trackingRow").remove();
});
```

But, you are attaching the event handler to only the original element (it won't be attached to the newly created `trackingRow` clones because they didn't exist at the time you installed your event handlers).  You need to pick a parent object that is a parent, but is static (not dynamically created) to attach the delegated event handler to.  Since you don't show your HTML, I will show the `document` object as the static parent, but you can likely find a static parent that is closer to the button which would be better:

```
// best to pick a static parent as close to deleteTracking as possible
// document will work, but it's better practice to pick a closer parent that
// is not dynamically created itself
$(document).on("click", ".deleteTracking", function () {
    $(this).closest(".trackingRow").remove();
});
```

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. That is such an obvious solution. Been staring at this code too long. :) Thanks!